# Yii : how to call rights's model from another controller

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Q : how do I retrieve the data at user/admincontroller of user extension from a table (authitem) of rights extension.

status : I am using rights and users extension. Both extensions are working fine by separately.

This is my code

```
$roles = AuthItem::model()->findAll('type=2');
```

This is my main.php

```
'import'=>array(

        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',

        // user extenstion

        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',


        // rights extensions
        'application.modules.rights.*', 
        'application.modules.rights.components.*', // Correct paths if necessary.
    ),
```

This is error msg

```
include(AuthItem.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you can't do that, you can;t access use AuthItem as model and retrieve information from it..

I faced this problem in last project where I used Rights, and needed `all users of a particular role`, `needed a dropdown of all roles, from which admin can choose`, `all roles assigned to a user`, etc requirements..

I wrote a good blog post having solution for such quesitions..

One of them, which seems to be your case is:

**Generate Check-Boxes of all available roles in the application..**

```
<?php
   $all_roles=new RAuthItemDataProvider('roles', array('type'=>2));
   $data=$all_roles->fetchData();
?>
<div>
    <label for="type_id">Type</label>
    <?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList("Type",'',CHtml::listData($data,'name','name'));?> 
</div>
```

You can find complete [blog post here](http://octathorpeweb.com/blog/2012/03/06/yii-rights-extension-rbac-role-based-access-control/)

Comment: I want to retrieve the roles. How can I? I tried $data_entry_users=Yii::app()->getAuthManager()->getItemType('2'); like this, but it isn't working.

Comment: roles?? all roles assigned to user id 2, or all roles in system?? btw both asnwets are there in blog

Comment: I followed your blog. but I got this error. include(RAuthItemDataProvider.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory. error code is $all_roles=new RAuthItemDataProvider('roles', array( 
    'type'=>2,
    ));.

Comment: Rajat Singhal, any idea? pls help me. My requirement is to get the roles of the system to display by checkbox

Comment: when I placed your code into actioncreate() of protected/module/user/controller/admincontroller, this error is coming out. include(RAuthItemDataProvider.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: you need to have the required files in import..I had -- `'application.modules.rights.*','application.modules.rights.components.*','application.modules.rights.components.dataproviders.*',`

Comment: Rajat, I created Superadmin to control whole system and Admin for create user only. But I don't want to show the superadmin role at Admin when Admin create a new user account. How could I do that?